# Websphere Server Error Launching Server Failed

Tags: server, websphere

Error received while starting the server

Reason:
Launching the server failed:
Location service deamon port 9000 is in use
Change each used port number to another unused port on the Ports page of 
the server configuration editor.

I already tried to restart the computer and the result still the same.
What else i try to resolve this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Stop the service/process which is using 9000 port or change its value
- Change that 9000 port in WebSphere configuration. Since you cannot start your server you have to do it manually, editing xml config files:

I'm assuming you have standalone single server, in case deployment mananger and multiple servers you need to find the correct one.

Go to the `PROFILE_ROOT\config\cells\YOUR_CELL_NAME\nodes\YOUR_NODE_NAME\serverindex.xml` and look for 9000 it should be `ORB_LISTENER_ADDRESS`. Change that port to free one. You can check ports that are already taken in system using for example `netstat -an`

Comment: Thanks for  reply. follow ur suggestion, found out that the i-net report is using the 9000 port, change the port number and it works.. Thank you..